# What's wrong with this C declaration Code?

Tags: c, windows, console, tui

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Tchar.h>

HANDLE wHnd;    // Handle to write to the console.
HANDLE rHnd;    // Handle to read from the console.

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    // Set up the handles for reading/writing:
    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    // Change the window title:
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Win32 Console Control Demo"));

    // Set up the required window size:
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, 79, 49};

    // Change the console window size:
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);

}
```

Some errors like this are reported:

```
'SMALL_RECT' : illegal use of this type as an expression  
missing ';' before identifier 'windowSize'
```

Comment: Did you mean to include `Windows.h` and `Tchar.h`, not `windows.h` and `tchar.h`?

Comment: Runs perfectly fine on CodeBlocks 10.05 as is.

Comment: @AlexanderBakulin Doesn't matter since Windows file systems are case insensitive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Right, it just struck my eye. Still I can't see any reason behind such an abuse of case insensitiveness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the MS C compiler which only supports the now ancient C90 standard. All your variables must be declared at the top of the function body.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{    
    // Set up the required window size:
    SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, 79, 49};

    // Set up the handles for reading/writing:
    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    // Change the window title:
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("Win32 Console Control Demo"));

    // Change the console window size:
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(wHnd, TRUE, &windowSize);
}
```

Painful, isn't it?!